# Pass data to startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do you pass data into startup.cs ?

This is for integration testing using `WebHostBuilder` and `TestServer`

I need to pass different data depending on the Test Fixture. So dont want to pull it in from a config file, for example

The data will be supplied to a registered Middleware in startup.cs

Docs seem to suggest this should work:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value"),
                });

            var configuration = configBuilder.Build();

            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration) // config added here
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
```

but when I inspect the Configuration object in startup.cs, the key is not present. And only the providers defined in startup.cs are available.

I am trying to do this in program.cs at the moment to test the concept, then will move to integration tests later

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Is there a better way to pass data into startup?

Comment: The configuration in `Main` and in `Startup` are completely different, they don't talk to each other. So whatever you set here is only for the web host setup. But how to send data to the `Startup` is another thing. Do you want it in the constructor or `Configure` or elsewhere?

Comment: I need it in Configure, when I set a particular Middleware, but the constructor would be fine too

Comment: You can add a `Service` for dependency injection in the `Main` actually, maybe this would work? I can add an example as an answer if that would be suitable. It could be a singleton containing the data you want, for example.

Comment: sure - any mechanism to pass in some data works for me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to send data into the `Startup` would be to register a service in `Main`. `WebHostBuilder` has `ConfigureServices` method which can be used just like the `ConfigureServices` method you can implement in the `Startup` class.

For example you can make a class with static variables (not the best idea but works)

```
public class DataContainer
{
   public static string Test;
}
```

Then set its values and add it as a singleton service

```
DataContainer.Test = "testing";

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(s => { s.AddSingleton(typeof(DataContainer)); })
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseConfiguration(configuration) // config added here
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

After this your `Startup` can just use the regular injection way to get this

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, DataContainer data)
{
  // data.Test is available here and has the value that has been set in Main
}
```

The injection of course works in any class and method after this, not just the constructor.

I'm not sure if this is any better than to actually create a class with static values by itself but if the class needs to be changed sometimes it can be made into an interface and the other usual injection benefits.

Comment: thanks - that works. just to note, your class doesn't have static properties, so I just new-ed up an instance - DataContainer container = new DataContainer {Test = "testing"}; - and then passed it in like this : .ConfigureServices(s => { s.AddSingleton(container); })

Comment: @ChrisCa Oops, forgot that. But yes, that also actually works and is better than statics.

Comment: thanks again - will leave this open for a while to see if there are any other ways to do this, but will accept this answer if not - cheers

Comment: This does not work with ASP.NET Core 3.  You cannot inject arbitrary types into the Startup class constructor anymore.

Comment: If you would like to use an instantiated instance of the class, you can use AddTransient() instead of AddSingleton() instead. This will let you pass in a set of values or other complex object without relying on a bounce pass using statics and will be safer in some situations.

Answer (score 12):

In ASP.NET Core 3, you can pass information as part of the configuration. In `Program.cs`, add a call to `.UseSettings()` and pass the configuration key and value as a string.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        webBuilder.UseSetting("CustomProperty", someProperty.ToString());
    })
```

Then, in your `Startup.cs` file, you should see the constructor defining a `Configuration` property.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    ...
}
```

Using that `Configuration` property, you can then access the value you passed from the `Program.cs` using `.GetValue()`.

```cs
Configuration.GetValue<TObjectType>("CustomProperty");
```

Comment: `UseSetting` and `GetSetting` only supports `String` values - you cannot pass arbitrary objects using that approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.usesetting?view=aspnetcore-5.0  - when you use `GetValue` it will try to perform object-binding.

Comment: Worked for me for a string value in .NET 6 with Startup and Program classes

Answer (score 6):

The solution **DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE**. Wanted to write it in all caps since at first I kept trying to make it work and did not see the comment from @Beevik

Best way I've found is to use the factory method for UseStartup instead of the generic one.

So instead of `UseStartup<Startup>()` you get `.UseStartup(x => new Startup(options))` where `options` is the custom parameter.

**UPDATE:** *This method is available only for Net5 and higher*

Comment: Could not find this method in .NET Core 3.1.  What am I missing?

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderextensions.usestartup?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-webhostbuilderextensions-usestartup-1(microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-iwebhostbuilder-system-func((microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-webhostbuildercontext-0)))) so maybe a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`

Comment: Ah, it looks like it's in .NET 5.0 +.  I'm currently on .NET Core 3.1.  Thanks!  (maybe clarify your answer to include this info?)