# Passing Object to ASP.NET with gRPC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

I'm upgrading a project from gRPC C# to gRPC for .NET.

I'm trying to pass an object to my service to take an action whenever the gRPC service is called. Previously in gRPC C# it was fairly straightforward and it looked something like this:

```
public class FooService : FooService.FooServiceBase
{ 
  private readonly ICustomObject _custom;

  public FooService(ICustomObject custom)
  {
     _custom = custom;
  }

  // action defined in my proto file
  public override Task<Response> SomeAction(Request request, ServerCallContext context)
  {
     return Task.FromResult(_custom.DoAction(request))
  }
}
```

Where I could simply pass a concrete implementation of `ICustomObject` into the constructor for `FooService` and go on about my day.

The implementation then would look something like:

```
public class Bar 
{
   private Grpc.Core.Server _server;

   public void StartService(ICustomObject custom) 
   {
     _server = new Grpc.Core.Server
     {
        Services = { GrpcGeneratedServiceObject.BindService(new FooService(custom)) }
     };

     _server.Start();
   }
}
```

However, I'm wildly lost after attempting to upgrade my project to gRPC for .NET and trying to wrap my head around encapsulating my service around ASP.NET Core. I'm following the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) but still lost.

I found this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721426/pass-data-to-startup-cs), but it doesn't seem to apply anymore to ASP.NET Core 3+.

I've got a few questions which seem to be all tied to my not fully understanding DI in ASP.NET Core:

- Do I need to write a custom constructor in `Startup.cs` and then somehow pass that into the Configure Method?
- How would I pass an instance of `ICustomObject` into the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` since it appears when `endpoints.MapGrpcService<FooService>()` this is an object created on demand?

To be clear, what I previously used gRPC for in my project was to abstract away having to deal with networking and TCP/IP in my project. I was able to just use gRPC encapsulate an endpoint that the rest of my project(s) could hook into and respond/reply to messages being received/sent.

Essentially - in my various projects I have many implementations of `ICustomObject` that need to be passed to the gRPC service so that depending on the implementation will do different things. At the moment, I don't fully understand if this is possible with ASP.NET and passing in various implementations of `ICustomObject`.

Comment: It sounds like you want `services.AddSingleton<FooService>()` up next to `service.AddGrpc()`? (Possibly also supplying the singleton instance explicitly). Basically: lifetime uses the DI approach from the framework, so: *tell it you only want one*

Comment: Possibly? It definitely seems like I could in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` just do `services.AddSingleton(new FooService(custom))` however where would I expose passing in `ICustomObject`?

I guess that's really the question here, I should edit my question to be more explicit. I have many implementations of ICustomObject in various projects that I want to be able to provide to the gRPC service.

Comment: Isn't that simply handled via the FooService constructor?

Comment: Right, but where could I from a public perspective pass it in? If I in `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` instantiate a singleton instance of `FooService` like mentioned, that means I need to pass in `ICustomObject`. The only reference I see to `Startup` in an ASP.NET project is when you create an instance of `IHostBuilder`, which as far as I see just has `webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();`. When the gRPC service comes online, I need to be able to pass an `ICustomObject`. This was a pattern I used to do in `Bar`, but isn't obvious to me in gRPC for .NET

Answer (score 0):

So I went down a rabbit hole for the past day trying to understand how ASP.NET Dependency Injection (DI) works, and for the moment I've found an okay workaround. Others more experienced in ASP.NET and DI in .NET, feel free to correct me.

When the `IHostBuilder` is constructed, I expanded it to the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args, CustomObject customObject)
{
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }).ConfigureServices(
            foo =>
            {
                foo.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ICustomObject), customObject))
            });
}
```

Where in the ServiceDescriptor above, I specify the type (in this case the interface) and a concrete object to pass in that has been instantiated (`customObject`), as mentioned in my original post, the `ICustomObject` I was passing in `Bar`. Notes [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-servicedescriptor-to-register-dependencies-in-asp-net-core/), [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/aspnet-core-dependency-injection-what-is-the-iservicecollection), and [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/aspnet-core-dependency-injection-what-is-the-iserviceprovider-and-how-is-it-built).

For those that follow the gRPC example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), the call in `Main(string[] args)` for the gRPC server gets expanded to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args, CustomObject customObject)
{
  CreateHostBuilder(args, customObject).Build().Run();
}
```

In `Startup.cs` I changed the following call in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` to add the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICustomObject, CustomObject>();
services.AddGrpc();
```

So that ASP.NET would know about the object itself.

**Since ASP.NET wants a concrete object when it starts up**, I moved the abstraction out to another interface that is supplied to `CustomObject` in it's constructor so that ASP.NET would be happy. Otherwise, I was getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987892/why-am-i-getting-the-error-cannot-instantiate-implementation-type-for-my-gener) error "Cannot instantiate implementation type", which based on what I read in that thread and elsewhere, ASP.NET always wants a concrete object to instantiate.

Also, thankfully, I did not have to change anything with my `FooService` implementation, I left the constructor for `FooService(ICustomObject custom)` the same and ASP.NET substitutes in the object I passed in earlier to do the processing.